# invalid 'trim' argument

Tags: r

Производится анализ временного ряда с использованием языка R и библиотеки prophet (также стоят библиотеки tidyverse, magrittr, dplyr, expm, ggplot2, devtools). Анализ производится по примеру который показан в книжке https://ranalytics.github.io/tsa-with-r/ch-intro-to-prophet.html#%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8 конкретно - 6 глава вся и в пункте 6.6.3 возникли проблемы.

что выполнили:

1. загружен csv-файл `df2<-read.csv(file.choose())`
2. написали функцию

   is_summer <- function(ds) {
   month <- as.numeric(format(ds, '%m'))
   return(month > 5 & month < 9)
   }

все нормально скомпилировалось

3. запустили функцию к данным с помощью `df2$summer <- is_summer(df2$ds)`
4. получили ошибку
   Error in format.default(ds, "%m") : invalid 'trim' argument

Уже чего только не делалось чтобы это решить
подскажите, пожалуйста, что можно предпринять

в процессе решить проблему выскакивали разные ошибки, например,
NAs introduced by coercion

Error in prettyNum(.Internal(format(x, trim, digits, nsmall, width, 3L, :
invalid 'trim' argument

Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
ошибка при оценке аргумента 'x' при выборе метода для функции 'format': non-numeric argument to binary operator

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, Ваша ошибка связана с тем, что не провели преобразование данных в формат tstibble, как указано в 1 главе той же книжки. После предварительного преобразования

```
library(tsibble)
df2 <- read_csv("bitcoin_price.csv") %>% as_tsibble(., key = NULL, index = ds)
```

обработка проходит без ошибок.